# PHP/NGINX: 301 redirect

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I was making a temporary redirect in PHP changing the headers.

However I'd like to make now a simple 301 page redirection directly in Nginx:

`http://domain.com/example.php?var=value`

to:

http://domain.com/index.htm

I tried:

```
location / {
    index index.htm index.php;
    rewrite example.php?var=value / permanent;
}
```

But it is not working...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running php at all? if so how do you do this? Via proxy or fastcgi?

Answer (score 4):

Simply put (out of "location / {}"):

`rewrite /example.php?var=value / permanent;`

By the way, PHP has a way to make redirections 301 also.